# Powershell string assign rows to variable

Tags: string, list, powershell

I am trying to assign / divide a string out to assign them to variables. The length of each row is random so I am kinda at a loss. Thanks for the help.

-String- 
Company 1
Employee 1
Employee 2
Employee 3
Company 2
Employee 1
Employee 2
Employee 3

I want to assign each line to a variable. $a = "company 1" $b = "employee 1" ect. The only stable variable in this string is each line of data is a different variable. The length of each line is unknown.

Thanks again!

Comment: Is there anything you have tried thus far? Your string is a newline delimeted string? And you want each value to be its own variable? What are you doing with this information as I am curious if there is a better way. But like my first question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to create a distinct variable for each row of your string, then use `New-Variable` in a loop:

```
$str = 'Company 1
Employee 1
Employee 2
Employee 3
Company 2
Employee 1
Employee 2
Employee 3'

# to know how many variables were created we will put them into array
$variables = @()
$i = 0
foreach ($row in ($str -split [Environment]::NewLine)) {
  # create new variable from row's value
  New-Variable -Name "row$i" -Value $row
  # and create a member of array
  $variables += [pscustomobject]@{Name = "row$i"; Value = $row}
  $i++
}

Write-Host "Total: $i"

foreach ($var in $variables) {
  Write-Host $var.Name $var.Value
}

# now we can get value from a variable 
Write-Host $row1
# or from array
Write-Host $variables[1].Name $variables[1].Value
```

But to operate on a collection of items it is really simplier to use arrays and other collection types without creating a variable per item:

```
$rows = @()
foreach ($row in ($str -split [Environment]::NewLine)) {
  $rows += $row
}
Write-Host "Total rows: $rows.Count"
# get the first row
$rows[0]
```